# Grafana Bar Chart with additional value displayed

Tags: grafana

I have a MS-Sql query, returning data in the following format.

| Description | Duration | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Category A | 34 | 2 |
| Category B | 29 | 15 |
| Category C | 23 | 27 |
| Category D | 11 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I am trying to build a bar chart that shows the `Description` column as a label, the `Duration` as the graphed value and additionally show the `Count` value next to the duration label, as shown below:

[image: excuse my poor ms paint]

If I exclude the `Count` column from my query, I get the category labels and graphs I expect, but if I include the count, suddenly the label appends 'Duration' on the end (eg: Category ADurtaion). I've tried setting various field overrides, but anything I do just makes my chart disappear and report `No Data`.
I tried following the examples [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/configure-standard-options/#standard-options-definitions) for display name, but none of that worked either.

I must be doing something wrong. Is this even possible?

Panel JSON:

```json
{
  "datasource": {
    "uid": "a4ad7525-0e00-4b7e-a652-033f42c16464",
    "type": "mssql"
  },
  "fieldConfig": {
    "defaults": {
      "mappings": [],
      "thresholds": {
        "mode": "absolute",
        "steps": [
          {
            "color": "#e1d301",
            "value": null
          },
          {
            "color": "#e03c32",
            "value": 15
          }
        ]
      },
      "color": {
        "mode": "thresholds"
      },
      "decimals": 0,
      "max": 40,
      "min": 0,
      "unit": "m"
    },
    "overrides": []
  },
  "gridPos": {
    "h": 12,
    "w": 8,
    "x": 8,
    "y": 6
  },
  "id": 6,
  "options": {
    "reduceOptions": {
      "values": true,
      "calcs": [
        "lastNotNull"
      ],
      "fields": "/^DowntimeDuration$/",
      "limit": 10
    },
    "orientation": "horizontal",
    "displayMode": "basic",
    "valueMode": "color",
    "showUnfilled": true,
    "minVizWidth": 0,
    "minVizHeight": 10
  },
  "pluginVersion": "9.5.1",
  "targets": [
    {
      "datasource": {
        "type": "mssql",
        "uid": "a4ad7525-0e00-4b7e-a652-033f42c16464"
      },
      "alias": "",
      "editorMode": "code",
      "format": "table",
      "rawQuery": true,
      "rawSql": "--omitted",
      "refId": "A",
      "sql": {
        "columns": [
          {
            "parameters": [],
            "type": "function"
          }
        ],
        "groupBy": [
          {
            "property": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "type": "groupBy"
          }
        ],
        "limit": 50
      }
    }
  ],
  "title": "Top 10 Downtime Reasons (Duration)",
  "type": "bargauge",
  "transformations": []
}
```

Comment: What you're describing is not achievable with barchart. If you want count as a text, you can simply include it into category name in your request. Or you can switch to table panel, instead of barchart, and configure duration to show as progress bar.